# DDD - What could be best fit for AggregateRoot and Entity for Transaction Domain

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, api-design

I'll preface this question by saying I am relatively new to DDD so I may be making some fundamental mistakes here!

I am working on a project which involves the concepts of Transactions (in the financial sense like Credit Card Transaction, or Single/Multiple CardTransaction.). A Transaction can be on Single card or Multiple Cards. The transaction amount may differ for each card. Also Cardholder or CardCustomer can be same or different.

A Transaction perform some specific business logic execution based on TransactionTypes (like Activate, Redeem ....).

A Transaction will perform following operations
     - Pre Transaction Validation on Card
     - Update Balance
     - Update Card Status
     - Update Customer info
     - Log Transaction

Now i am confused to decide what could be my aggregateroot here.

Approach 1

Use transaction an an entity holding cardid, amount, customerid, transactiontype, transactionlogid as a ValueObject  and Card, CardAmountSummary, CardCustomer, and TransactionLog as an entity
Create Seperate AggreateRoot for  SinglegiftCardTransaction, MultipleGiftCardTransaction, BookletTransaction, WalletTransaction each will act as a wrapper for Transaction/s.
Transaction boundary may differ based on bulk or single transaction.

Approach 2

Use Transaction as a AggregateRoot  holding a list of Cards, Each Card will have CustomerId, Amount, CardAmountSummaryId, transactionlogid, transactiontypeid as a Value object.

What would be best fit for AggreateRoot and Entities here ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, the issue you are describing is finding a balance between choosing the which objects should "own" the data, and which objects should "use" that data. While DDD (and OOP in general) is a paradigm defined by bringing data and behavior together, the specific *kind* of behavior you are describing simply cannot be contained within the same object as the own that "owns" the data. With the above in mind, the answer to your question is... neither. Coordination of business rules *between* entities is best left for a domain service.

Consider the example of withdrawing money (`withdraw`) from your `BankAccount` using an `ATM`. The issue here is there are *two* transactions that must complete in order for money to be dispensed, each with their *own* business rules that need to be enforced. The `ATM.dispense` method is subject to the rule that the ATM must (physically) have enough currency to dispense the amount desired. And your `BankAccount.debit` method requires that you have the available funds in your account. The only way to transactionally mandate that both rules are enforced without creating a direct dependency between the `ATM` and `BankAccount` entities is to create an `ATMService` object that can coordinate/mediate the business process between the two entities that actually "own" the data. The body of the `withdraw` method might look like:

```
// each of these could throw an exception 
atm.dispense( amount );
account.debit( amount );
```

Importantly, the `ATM.withdraw` method is carried out as part of a single transaction. So if there is an error in any part of the process, nothing is committed (all or nothing). Transaction `id` and the like could be added and used for event correlation if needed.

The above example is similar to your first option, but differs in that the `ATMService` does not "own" any data at all (it is not, itself, an aggregate). The data, and intermediary transactions are all owned and carried out by the appropriate entities.

For long-running or async processes, you could introduce a process manager to help mediate a work-flow as well.